# Binary Tree Not Showing Nodes Present Python

Tags: python, binary-tree

I'm trying to implement a binary tree with `insert` and `preorder` methods.

After adding elements to the tree, only one element is displayed.

Can someone let me know where I'm wrong.

Below is code:

```
class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.value)

class BinaryTree(object):

    def __init__(self, root=None):
        self.root = root

    def add(self, value):
        val = self.root
        if not val:
            self.root = value
            val = value

        elif not val.left:
            val = value
        elif not val.right:
            val = value
        else:
            self.left = val.left.add(value)
        return val

    def preorder(self):
        val = self.root
        if not val: # this will handle the case when root node is None.
            return 
        print(val)
        if val.left:
            val.left.preorder()
        if val.right:
            val.right.preorder()


def main():

    binary_tree = BinaryTree()

    print("Adding nodes to the tree")
    for i in range(1, 11):
        node = Node(i)
        binary_tree.add(node)

    print("Printing preorder...")
    binary_tree.preorder()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output

```
Adding nodes to the tree
Printing preorder...
1
```

Comment: you asked a similar question today. have you tried debugging this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a few different errors. Some relate to how you modify `self.root` (or fail to), others have to do with attempts at recursion on the wrong types.

The first issue, which is why your code fails silently, has to do with your `BinaryTree.add` method, which does nothing when the tree is empty. The problem is that you initialize a local variable `val` to be equal to your root node (if you have one), and then later rebind it to some other value. But that never changes the root value at all, only the local `val` variable.

I suggest you get rid of `val` all together, and instead read and write `self.root` directly. Then you'll actually make some progress, and see the other issues.

Here's a start:

```
def add(self, value):
    if self.root is None:
        self.root = value
    elif self.root.left.left is None:
        self.root.left = value
    ...
```

The other issues I mention are both similar, though one occurs in `BinaryTree.add` and the other in `BinaryTree.preorder`. The issue is that you try to call the same method (`add` or `preorder`) on one of the children of your root node. But the nodes are `Node` instances, and don't have the methods that you've defined in the `BinaryTree` class.

This issue doesn't have as obvious a solution as the previous one. One idea might be to move the logic for the methods into the `Node` class (where you can recurse easily), and leave only the empty-tree handling code in the `BinaryTree` methods (everything else gets delegated to the root node).